# vba expected end sub

Tags: function, loops, excel, vba

This program is intended to select rows among data that contain the value contained in the array 'names'. The selected rows are then cut-pasted into a different sheet.

When I run this code, I keep getting the error 'compile error: expected end sub'. I've looked around a few places and nothing seems to work.

EDIT: changed row array to string array using function below. Same error.

EDIT: removed 'set' from function. Same error =/

```
Function IsInArray(ToBeFound, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, ToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function


Function RangeToStringArray(myRange as range) as String() 'Credit to JA Daling
    ReDim strArray(myRange.Cells.Count - 1) As String
    Dim idx As Long
    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In myRange
        strArray(idx) = c.Text
        idx = idx + 1
    Next c
    RangeToStringArray = strArray
End Function

Sub Removedata()
    Dim i As Integer: i = 12
    Dim names: names = RangeToStringArray(Sheets("Pivot 1").Range("F18:F44"))
    While i < 554
        If IsInArray(Sheets("Raw data test").Cells(i, 16).Value, names) = True Then
            Sheets("Raw data test").Range(Sheets("Raw data test").Cells(1, 16), Sheets("Raw data test").Cells(26, 16)).Cut
            Sheets("Raw Data Out of Scope").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: `(Filter(arr, ToBeFound)` thats a type mismatch to start off with. The second argument has to be a `String` not an array

Comment: Is this all your code in the module? Don't use the `:` method to declare variables, either, that's not really the most readable code.

Comment: This is all the code in the module, yes.

Comment: Unable to *test* the code, but it *does* compile as long as you remove the `Set` from `Set strArray(idx) = c.Text`.

Comment: Note: `Filter` may not give you what you want, in my experience that returns partial matches (e.g., if you search for "50", it will return true if the array contains "500" etc.)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with other options other than 'filter' - what would you suggest?

Also, edited.

Comment: Which lines are highlighted when you compile the code manually. In a short test, the VBA editor highlights which line it complains about. Use Debug > Compile VBAProject to compile the code.

Comment: that's odd... you could try `Do Until i >= 554 ... Loop` instead of the `While...Wend` structure, but I still would not expect either to give you any problems.

Comment: As for alternatve to filter, the only real solution I use is a simple brute force iteration over the array.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `Set` a `String` variable.

Change this line: `Set strArray(idx) = c.Text` to the following

```
strArray(idx) = c.Text
```

I found this by clicking `Debug > Compile VBA Project` in the menu of the VBA window.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out! For whatever reason, copy-pasting the code into a new module did the trick. Thank you everyone for helping out with this!